# Community SSO using JWT

Tags: community, single-sign-on, jwt

We are setting up a Salesforce Community and our community members should be able to automatically login from 3rd party and at their end they will create the JWT payload and via connected app callback_url (SFCommunity) should automatically logged-in. Also, I don't have permission to use SAML SSO.

How can I generate the login_url and test this from dev console?

(Assumption :- 1 connected app, via Developer console HTTP request will provide session or token and we can generate the url for direct login)

Comment: Refer below link.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315176&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Link is useful when we setup SAML SSO then https://abc.force.com/login?so={orgid}.
I need to setup JWT token SSO.

Comment: have you tried with your community url?